# g++ not creating "a.out" file

Tags: c++, g++

btw, I know this is a duplicate, *but I can't find the answer!*

I'm trying to make a C++ file that compiles and runs another C++ file and checks if the output is correct or incorrect (I know that's kinda weird).

(the Desktop folder has a eval.cpp and an a.out + a "test" folder 
the test folder has got main.cpp, tytytyt.in, tytytyt.out, tytytyt.ok)

eval.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
ifstream fa("~/Desktop/test/tytytyt.out");
ifstream fok("~/Desktop/test/tytytyt.ok");
string filename;
int a, ok;
int main()
{
    cout << "In ce folder se afla fisierul pe care ai dori sa testezi? \n";
    cin >> filename;
    string str = "g++ -o a.out" + filename;
    const char * command = str.c_str();
    cout << "Compilare sursa cu ajutorul comenzii " << command << " ... \n";
    system(command);
    cout << "Rulare fisier... \n";
    system("~/Desktop/test/a.out");
    fa >> a;
    fok >> ok;

    if(a == ok) cout << "Corect!";
    else cout << "Incorect!";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run `~/Desktop$ g++ eval.cpp` it creates an `a.out` file.
Then I run `~/Desktop$ ./a.out`.
When my program prints `In ce folder se afla fisierul pe care ai dori sa testezi?` and I write `~/Desktop/test/main.cpp`, the program prints 
`Compilare sursa cu ajutorul comenzii g++ ~/Desktop/test/main.cpp ...`
`Rulare fisier...`
and then comes the error: `sh: 1: /home/steven/Desktop/test/a.out: not found` 
and if I check the test folder, the file `a.out` doesn't exist.

Can someone help me?
`

Comment: What are you trying to do finally?

Comment: checking if the output is correct or incorrect

Comment: Why do you expect the binary to be in `test` subdirectory? No part of the build command mentions it. You also probably need a space between `a.out` and the input file name.

Comment: but how can i put the `a.out` in `test`?

Comment: i don't know...

Comment: @Stevineon How did you specify that `main.cpp` was in `test`? Why not try the same thing for your output file?

Comment: @Stevineon, `a.out` is created in your current working directory (can be queried with `pwd` command) and not in the same directory as `main.cpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having

> ```
> string str = "g++ -o a.out" + filename;
> const char * command = str.c_str();
> cout << "Compilare sursa cu ajutorul comenzii " << command << " ... \n";
> system(command);
> ```

if the compilation success *a.out* is produced in the current directory because you do not specify where it must be generated

if you want to generate `~/Desktop/test/a.out` replace

> string str = "g++ -o a.out" + filename;

by

```
string str = "g++ -o ~/Desktop/test/a.out" + filename;
```

except that I do not understand how the compilation can be done because there is no space after `a.out` to be separated with the *filename*, *filename* is set through `cin >> filename;` so it is a word and cannot starts by a space or an other separator, are you sure the compilation was done ? You do not even test the result of *system* ...

For me it must be

```
string str = "g++ -o ~/Desktop/test/a.out " + filename;
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand :D